# I've seen a japanese font but no font detecter manage to detect japanese characters

Tags: japanese

Did someone can help me finding this font ? ^^"

> 僕は笑っていたいんです泣きたい時は泣きたいんです No Logic
> [image]

It's the font on this music
https://youtu.be/-7QijddBQvg?t=193

Answer (score 1):

A well-known square typeface family [ＤＦＰ綜藝体](https://dfo.dynacw.co.jp/fontlist/fontlist_detail.aspx?sid=164) from DynaComware, with necessary modification.

[image: sample]

My sample uses the W7 weight.

**Edit**: the font preview interface seems to give me only the sample of the variant ＤＦ綜藝体, where the Latin letters are monospaced. The video uses proportional one [in the same family](https://designpocket.jp/dl_font_category/detail.aspx?bid=15346).